# PHP error level differs from Fatal to warning on same error

Tags: php

I have some SQL that throws an incorrect syntax message:

```
$sSQL = "SELECTTTT row from Table";
```

The first iteration gets caught and produces a Fatal Error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]Incorrect syntax near 'SELECTTTT'.

The second iteration, produces a warning and subsiquently isn't caught

> Warning: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]:

```
for ($i=0; $i < 2; $i++) { 

    try {

        $st->execute($sSQL);

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        echo $e->GetMessage();
        var_export($e->getTrace()); 

    }

}
```

can someone please explain what im missing here? Since the command hasnt changed, why is the error produced differing?

Comment: This is just a guess, but maybe PDO prepares the query in the background, and kind of remembers it as prepared in the second iteration. And because it's already been prepared it gets run, but that doesn't give the detailed error message.

Comment: that would make some sense. Will do a test and re-init the pdo connection, see if same happens

Comment: yep you'r spot on! Although closing the connection every time isn't really a desired solution :( Would you have any idea how to get PDO to 'forget' the last statement?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a PHP person. But database thingies work the same way everywhere, so this fit. I suggest you consult the documentation. Maybe you can explicitly prepare in that loop. Or jump out of the loop if your query has a syntax error. Unless you are building the SQL inside of the loop there is no need to continue iterating if the query is broken.

Comment: The exception which you `catch` and `echo` actually says *"Uncaught exception…"*?

Comment: @deceze can a _warning_ be caught with `catch`? Can't that just be a warning that gets printed to STDERR?

Comment: @simbabque Nope, totally different mechanism. Whatever is finally catching and outputting the exception message is adding the "Warning", "Fatal error" and "Uncaught exception" to the exception message…

Comment: thanks simbabque, unfortunately I'm constructing some sql in the loop. Its ok if it fails, I just need to record that it has and continue building the rest of my sql.

Comment: Then I guess you need to explicitly prepare it every time. What's `$st`? A statement handle, or the database handle? If it's a statement handle, make a new one...

Comment: yeah its a statement handle, sounds like a good idea too, thanks! Happy to accept if you want to answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my [initial comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1331451/simbabque):

> This is just a guess, but maybe PDO prepares the query in the
>   background, and kind of remembers it as prepared in the second
>   iteration. And because it's already been prepared it gets run, but
>   that doesn't give the detailed error message

Therefore I believe you need to [prepare a new statement handle](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) in every iteration, because your query is different every time.

```
// connect outside of the loop
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass); 

for ($i=0; $i < 2; $i++) { 

    try {
        // build the query inside of the loop
        $sSQL = "SELECTTTT row from Table"; // this is variable

        // prepare a fresh statement handle for your SQL in every iteration
        $st = $dbh->prepare($sSQL);        

        // run this specific query
        $st->execute();
    } catch (Exception $e) {

        echo $e->GetMessage();
        var_export($e->getTrace()); 

    }
}
```

Otherwise you're just executing the first query that has already been prepare and passing the value of `$sSQL` as an argument to `execute`.

Comment: I was trying to find a reference in the docs for my last statement, but I am not used to the PHP documentation and can't find it right now. Please feel free to edit a source into this answer.

Comment: thanks simbabque. Unfortunately this wont solve the issue, my fault I mis read the above comment. I think im going to be forced to create a new instance of connection each time? Your first comment was probably most useful, might be worth including incase it helps anyone later on

Comment: sorry... I was planning on editing your answer if you didnt respond. Guess I should have waited until at least then.. Thanks again :)

Comment: @atoms But I really don't see why you should need to reconnect every time. But if you're making SQL queries programmatically and they can contain syntax errors I think you have a different problem altogether. Make sure you sanitize your user input properly or some mom might exploit it. ;)

Comment: yeah your right, will add some more control before it gets to this stage. Cheers simbabque

Comment: @atoms note that I had a mistake in there. `execute()` needs no argument.